# Empty ref('') variable after assigning .value to this variable in composition API vue 3

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm making a request with a ref property, **after** I assign a string to a ref('') the .value it is empty in the request when I'm calling the method inside the onMounted(), why is that possible? but when I print  in console **before** the request the variable it shows the expected value. I share the code

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { onMounted, ref, watch } from 'vue'
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'
import axios from 'axios'
import CustomTable from './CustomTable.vue'

const router = useRouter()
let today: Date
let fechaColaEmails = ref('')

//llamada http
const url = `${import.meta.env.VITE_APP_ROOT_API}${
  import.meta.env.VITE_BACKEND_DASHBOARD_DESA
}/emails?fecha=${fechaColaEmails.value}`

async function pedirEmails() {
  try {
    console.log('dentro del metodo pedir emails: ' + url)
    const { data } = await axios.get<any[]>(url)
    emails.value = data
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}

async function submitFecha(fecha: any) {
  let fechT: string = fecha.target.value
  let arrayFecha = fechT.split('-')
  fechaColaEmails.value = arrayFecha[2] + '/' + arrayFecha[1] + '/' + arrayFecha[0]
  console.log('hola')
}

onMounted(async () => {
  today = new Date()
  let dd = String(today.getDate())
  let mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1) //January is 0!
  let yyyy = today.getFullYear()
  fechaColaEmails.value = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy
  console.log('onMounted: ', fechaColaEmails.value)
  console.log('esta es la peticion en onmounted: ' + url)
  await pedirEmails()
  console.log('esta es la peticion despues de pedirla: ' + url)
})

function ruta(event: number): void {
  router.push({ name: 'detallesemail', params: { contador: event } })
}
let emails = ref([
  {  }
])
</script>
```

Comment: There is no computed property in your code. My guess is that `url` should be one? Or you could build the url before you make the request, urls usually don't have to be reactive

Comment: that's the url I use to make the request the issue it's when I call it the ${fechaColaEmails.value} is empty

Comment: `url` is generated once, when it is declared and `fechaColaEmails` is empty. It does not react to changes to `fechaColaEmails`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you assume `url` is a computed property, that changes when you change `fechaColaEmails`. But it is just a string:

```
let fechaColaEmails = ref('')

const url = `${import.meta.env.VITE_APP_ROOT_API}${
  import.meta.env.VITE_BACKEND_DASHBOARD_DESA
}/emails?fecha=${fechaColaEmails.value}` // <---- fechaColaEmails.value will be resolved immediatelly to ''
```

If you want to make it responsive, you need to put it into an actual computed property:

```
const url = computed(() => `...fecha=${fechaColaEmails.value}`)
```

Now `url` is recomputed everytime `fechaColaEmails` change.

---

You might want to check if it is enough to build the `url` only when you actually need it, there is no point in making values reactive if you don't need to react to them:

```
async function pedirEmails() {
  const url = `...`
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get<any[]>(url)
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ah you 're right about the computed property thanks for your answer, but I do actually need to react to the url due to input date selector in order to make new requests.